App to display filtered public streaming page
I am trying to take a public streaming page (think of Youtube or Apple Music), filter out some DOM elements according to certain rules, and then serve the page (in a way that I can later package as a mobile app). This is only for personal use. My approach so far was to create a Node.js proxy server using Express. The server fetches the target website, modifies its HTML to route resources through the proxy, and serves the content in an iframe (using http-proxy-middleware to handle API requests and CORS issues). However, I keep running into a multitude of CORS issues that I can't seem to solve. While I can load the overall page, the streaming content never loads.
I am starting to wonder: is this even the right approach or should I go about this differently?
